# Adding more fields to google contact with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add more information to a contact created through Google Apps Script, but I keep getting an error:

> "Service error: ContactsApp: Mismatch: etags =
>   ["SX48fjVSLit7I2A9WhNQE0kLQAI."], version = "

I'm trying to do it using this code:

```
var newContact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, email);
newContact.setNickName(nickname);
```

The variables firstName, lastName, email, and nickname are all pulled from a google spreadsheet.

The error always occurs during the second line of code, whenever I try to add more information to the contact, regardless of what information I try to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [Issue 1528](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1528). A workaround is mentioned in the link provided to the issue which you can use.